# How to code parallel tasks using INET/OMNET?

Tags: parallel-processing, omnet++, inet

```
// Example:

TASK1() {
    broadcast(SG, E);    
}

TASK2() {
    receive_broadcast(SG, E);    
}

TASK3() {
    cleanup_data_stuctures(); // time trigger to wake up
}
```

There are no examples, codes or tips about this... :-/

Answer (score 3):

OMNeT++ is a *discrete event simulation* framework. Discrete event simulation does not model a system through tasks running in parallel, but through the system's reaction to events (each of which takes zero time).

In your example, you will want to react to three different types of event:

1. What happens when an event signals that it is time for cleanup?
2. What happens when an event signals that a broadcast is to be sent? To give an example, this event handler might schedule an event notifying a different part of your simulation that a broadcast has arrived.
3. What happens when an event signals that a broadcast has arrived? Here, the event handler might output a log message.

The OMNeT++ user manual's [Section 4.1.1 ("Discrete Event Simulation")](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec:simple-modules:discrete-event-simulation) goes over this concept briefly.